# Regex split by '_', apart from fourth occurrence

Tags: c#, regex

I may have either of the following strings, and I want to get the associated output:

Input:`a_b_c_d_e`, expected output: `a, b, c, d_e`

Input:`a_b_c_d`, expected output: `a, b, c, d`

How can I do this with Regex?

Comment: What language/tool are you using? Most of the times you can limit the output with a parameter within the used function.

Comment: Check out the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda(v=vs.110).aspx). Basically you will need to split on `_` and set the `count` parameter accordingly

Comment: I've done the following so far ([^_][^_]+). Just not entirely sure where to put the counts.

Comment: Man, it's really simple: `string input = "a_b_c_d_e"; char delimiter = '_'; string [] split = input.Split(delimiter, 4);`

Comment: Perhaps I should have made clear; I know how to split a string in code, but we have a lot of these strings that we need to split in different ways, so I want to make it generic and config based, not hard coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may split using this expression:

```
(?<!^(?:[^_]*_[^_]*){3})_
```

This matches any underscore apart from that prepended by a string with exactly 3 underscores in it.

Demo: https://ideone.com/VZGv4t